# Failed to deploy web application to IIS using VS2019 - DLL is locked

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-8, msdeploy

I have this application that I am trying to deploy on my production environment.
I am using the MSDeploy webPublish Method and it always fail at the end with the following message.

```
Web deployment task failed. (Web Deploy cannot modify the file 'Castle.Core.dll' on the destination because it is locked by an external process.  In order to allow the publish operation to succeed, you may need to either restart your application to release the lock, or use the AppOffline rule handler for .Net applications on your next publish attempt
```

I have tried several solutions:

- Adding `<EnableMSDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>` in my pubxml but I got the same error
- Stop IIS on the destination server, try to publish but I got the same "locked DLL" error

What would be the other ways to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to restart visual studio and deploy again? Close visual studio will release dll.

Comment: You can use lockhunter to see what is locking your dll, it might give you relevant infos. https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/lockhunter